# Rotation matrix to construct canonical form of a conic

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, conic-sections, quadratic-forms, plane-curves

I want to find the canonical form of the following conic:
$$C: 9x^2+4xy+6y^2-10=0.$$
I've found $C$ is a non-degenerate ellipses (computing the cubic and the quadratic invariant), and then I've studied the characteristic polynomial
$$p(t)=\det
\begin{pmatrix}
9-t & 2\\
2 & 6-t\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The eigenvalue are $t_1=5,t_2=10$, with associated eigenvectors $(-1,2)$, $(2,1)$. Thus I construct the rotation matrix $R$ by putting in columns the normalized eigenvectors (taking care that $\det(R)=1$):

$$ R=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2\\
-2 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then $(x, y)^t=R(x',y')^t$, and after some computations I find the canonical form
$$\frac{1}{2}x'^2+\frac{4}{5}y'^2=1.$$

**Question:** The solution presented in the book says the canonical form is $$2x'^2+y'^2=2,$$
because the rotation matrix they use is different:

$$ R=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1\\
1 & 2\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Why my rotation matrix is *wrong*? How can I detect which rotation I should construct? From what I understand it suffices to put on columns the eigenvectors and pay attention the determinant is one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If$$q(x,y)=9x^2+4xy+6y^2-10$$and$$x'=\frac1{\sqrt5}(x+2y)\ \text{and}\  y'=\frac1{\sqrt5}(-2x+y),$$then $q(x',y')=5x^2+10y^2-10$. So, $q(x',y')=0\iff\frac12x^2+y^2=1$.

Comment: I see, I miscomputed the coefficient of $y'^2$ (10 and not 8): from that it follows the two canonical form coincide. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.